# How are these tables related?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, left-join, entity-relationship

Say I run an online business where you can order products from my website, and I have a database with two tables:

Table `order` with the fields `order_number, customer_ID, address`

Table `customer` with the fields `customer_ID, first_name, last_name`

To get a full, detailed 'report' of the order, I would perform a LEFT JOIN to concatenate data from the order table to include the customer's first and last names along with their address and order number.

My question is, how are these tables related? Are they at all? What would an entity relationship diagram look like? Separately they don't seem to interact and act more like lookup tables for each other.

Comment: they are related as 1 to many (1 customer has many orders, but 1 order has 1 customer)

Answer (score 1):

An order would always have a customer, no? So it is not a left but inner join.

What links them is the customer_id. So your SQL is simply:

```
select o.order_number, o.customer_ID, o.address, 
    c.first_name, c.last_name
from orders o
inner join customer c on o.customer_ID = c.customer_ID;
```

Entity relationship:

Order                     Customer
Customer_Id 0...N >---+ 1 Customer_Id
...                   ...

[image: Customer-Orders Entity Diagram]

This EF relation is from MS SQL Server's sample database Northwind. In that sample database, just like yours, there are Customers and Orders. Customers and Orders tables are related via the CustomerId fields in both tables (it is the primary key in Customers, and foreign key in Orders table). When you model that as an Entity relation than you have the above diagram. Customer entity have an "Orders" navigation property (via customerId) that points to a particular Customer's Orders. And Order entity have a navigation property that points to its Customer (again via CustomerId). The relation is 1 to 0 or many (1 - *), meaning a Customer might have 0 or more Orders.

When you do the join from Customer's side, you use a LEFT join "if you want to see all Customers regardless they have Order(s) or not" - 0 or more Order(s). If you want to see only those with Order(s) then you use an inner join.

When you do the join from Orders' side, then an Order must have a Customer so it can't be a LEFT join. It is an INNER join.

You can check the relation from both sides using the connecting CustomerId field.

You wouldn't have a separate table for "OrderId, CustomerId" as it is not many-to-many relation (it would be pure redundancy and would create normalization anomalies).

Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: `Order Customer Customer_Id 0...N >---+ 1 Customer_Id` Could you elaborate on what you mean here? I'm not familiar with this syntax

Comment: Sorry I simply used the text based syntax. Added a picture and more explanations. HTH.

Comment: @CetinBasoz: Your answer is not based on the entity-relationship model.

Comment: The gist of the question is about table relations - "My question is, how are these tables related?" and the paragraph above it.

Comment: The question is tagged `entity-relationship` but your answer is based on Entity Framework which is an implementation of the network data model.

Comment: It is also tagged as sql, mysql, left-join and database if you have missed. Anyway not worth discussing.

Answer (score 0):

In the entity-relationship model, we don't relate tables.  Instead, we relate entities which are represented by their key values.  In your example, the `customer` entity (represented by `customer_ID`) has a one-to-many relationship with the `order` entity (represented by `order_number`) and this relationship is recorded in the `order` table (where `order_number` is associated with `customer_ID`).  If we were to strictly follow the ER model, we would record `(order_number, customer_ID)` (a relationship relation) in a separate table from `(order_number, address)` (an entity relation).

If there's a foreign key constraint on `order.customer_ID` referencing `customer.customer_ID`, that's a subset relation that ensures that every order's customer is a known customer.  Thus, the relation between the tables and the relation between the entities is not the same thing.

The relational model allows us to relate (join) tables in any way we need.  The obvious join for your example would be on the shared domain `customer_ID`, but I could just as easily find orders which contain a customer's `last_name` in its delivery `address`.

An ER diagram for your example could look like this:

[image: Customer Order ER diagram]

Comment: I understand and your diagram makes it very clear. How come there isn't a customer_id branch coming from 'order'? Is it because customer_id is the primary key for the customer table so is only shown there?

Comment: Yes, customer_id represents an entity and the association between order_number and customer_id is considered a relationship rather than an attribute.  In ER, attributes are mappings from entity sets to value sets while relationships are associations among entity sets.

Comment: "I could just as easily find orders which contain a customer's last_name in its delivery address" - I would disagree with all due my respect. An invoice address and bill to address might be totally different things, with no connection to the Customer. Having a separate Address entity and relating to it is an option but that is another matter. In this little model, you cannot use Address instead. An Order might have been Ordered by Customer "John Doe" and sent to someone which happens to be another Customer "Frank Smith".

Comment: @CetinBasoz I'm not sure what you mean.  My point is that the relational model allows me to join tables in any way I want, e.g. `SELECT * FROM customer c JOIN order o ON LOCATE(c.last_name, o.address) > 0`.  Navigational data models have fixed access paths which make ad-hoc queries difficult and inefficient.

Comment: What do invoice address and billing address and address entities have to do with OP's question?  `In this little model, you cannot use Address instead.`  Instead of what?  `An Order might have been Ordered by Customer "John Doe" and sent to someone which happens to be another Customer "Frank Smith"`  Again, what does that have to do with OP's question?  I gave SQL to demonstrate exactly how easy it is to do what I said.  Where am I wrong?

Comment: You are saying "I could just as easily find ... ". I got that as if you were implying you could relate an order to its customer that way. I might have got you wrong. Your SQL was also implying that and that made me think wrong maybe. I don't understand what you implied then.

Comment: Again, my point and my example was to show that the relational model allows us to relate tables in any possible way, not just via predefined navigation paths.  I realize that from a network model point of view, entity relationships and foreign key constraints look like the same thing, and dynamic relations aren't even considered as such, which is why I distinguished them.

Comment: @CetinBasoz When @ reaanb wrote "I could just as easily find orders which contain a customer's last_name in its delivery address" he just used "delivery address of an order" to mean your "address of an order" (whatever you meant by it). So his query returns rows of values (of CUSTOMER & ORDER) that participate in the relationship/association "there exist values for ADDRESS, FIRST_NAME & LAST_NAME where customer CUSTOMER has name FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME AND order ORDER has customer CUSTOMER and address ADDRESS AND LAST_NAME is a substring of ADDRESS". (See also my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how are these tables related? Are they at all? What
>   would an entity relationship diagram look like? Separately they don't
>   seem to interact and act more like lookup tables for each other.

When dealing with data modeling in an ER-Diagram, more in the conceptual model, we should never start thinking of tables, primary keys, foreign keys and stuff as this is for the later model to the conceptual model, the logical model.

By modeling entities in ER-Diagram, we must always recognize them by their attributes/properties. The entities become concrete when we can find properties in them. I feel a lack of context here, so I'll proceed with a guess:

- If you need to persist products in your database, and you need to
  save the attributes/properties of them, then we have a Products
  entity.
- If you need to persist clients/users in your database along with
  their properties/attributes, then we have a Customers entity.

According to what you said, customers are able to purchase products. So, you have to relate these two entities in any way. With this in mind, stop and think about the following:

- You need to persist purchases/orders.
- Purchases/orders show which users bought which products.

By linking products and customers, what would we get? The purchasing/orders event, right?

We would then have two entities relating to each other forming the purchasing (or "orders", you name it) event. This event is formed by the need for the present business rules (your rules). You as modeler you need to persist the orders, and you know that products and customers relate in some way, so you can create a relationship between the two entities representing the orders event.

As has been well discussed in other answers, there is the need of separation of attributes here. If the field "address" is where a user lives, not where the product will be delivered, then this attribute must exist in the Customers entity.

If this field/attribute/property is the final location of delivery, it should remain in the relationship orders created between the two entities, customers and products.

Let's talk now about cardinality. If a customer can purchase/order more than one product, and the same product can be purchased by more than one user, then we have a N-N relationship here. I believe this is your case.

Based on everything that was said, we find the following conceptual model:

[image]

By decomposing this model, and developing the logic model, we would have:

[image]

Now, for what reason we end up with this kind of model?

Relations N-N allow the existence of properties/attributes (if needed), so we can have attributes/properties in the relation Orders, resulting in an ORDERS table with the fields shown. This table represents the purchases/orders made by users/customers.

And for what reason the existence of "Products from orders"?

We need to say what products were purchased in which purchases/orders, especially showing how many of the same type are acquired. In N-N relationships, some properties induces the appearance of new relations which become tables later. In such situations, it is the discretion of the modeler.

In "Products from orders" entity we have a composite primary key, represented by foreign keys.

With this type of model, you can see:

- Which users made purchases/orders.
- Which purchases/orders were made by which users.
- Which products belong to which purchases/orders.
- Which products have been acquired by which users.
- How many products of a type were purchased/ordered.

Using the date field, you can find out how many purchases were made in periods:

- Weeks.
- Months.
- Years.
- Quarters.
- Etc.

If you are interested, see also:

[E-R diagram confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391046/e-r-diagram-confusion/35616442#35616442)

If you have any questions, please comment and I will answer.I hope I've helped a bit.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

"Related" is a vague and confusing term. This is because "relationship" gets used in two different ways: as "association" (between values) and as "foreign key" (between tables).

You do not need to know anything about how tables are "related" by foreign keys or common columns in order to query. What matters is how values in a query's result rows are related/associated by the query. The important relationships/associations are (represented by) the *tables*.

From a relational perspective, there would be a foreign key from Order referencing Customer on customer_id.

A Chen-style ER diagram would have Order and Customer entity types (boxes) and an Orders relationship type (diamond) with participations (lines) from Orders to Order and to Customer. It would have a table for each type. This is an example of perfectly sensible relational design that the ER model, with its artificial and perverse distinction between entities and relationships, cannot capture. People will use a database design like yours to implement such an ER design, though. Even though the ER design isn't, then, the design.

--

When using a database, values are used to identify entities or as property names and magnitudes. Each base table holds the rows of values that participate in some relationship/association given by the DBA. Each query result holds the rows of values that participate in a relation/association that is a combination of conditions and the relationships/associations of the base tables it mentions. All you need to know to query is the relationships/associations of tables.

```
Order -- order ORDER_NUMBER is by customer CUSTOMER_ID to address ADDRESS
Customer -- customer CUSTOMER_ID is named FIRST_NAME LAST NAME
Order JOIN (Customer WHERE FIRST_NAME='Eddie')
    -- order ORDER_NUMBER is by customer CUSTOMER_ID to address ADDRESS
    AND customer CUSTOMER_ID is named FIRST_NAME LAST NAME
    AND  FIRST_NAME='Eddie'
```

Sometimes values for a list of columns in a row of one table must also appear as values for a list of columns in another table or that table. This is because if the listed values and others satisfy one table's relationship/association then the listed values and yet others will satisfy the other table's relationship/association.

```
/* IF there exist ORDER_ID & ADDRESS satisfying
       order ORDER_NUMBER is by customer CUSTOMER_ID to address ADDRESS
   THEN there exist FIRST_NAME & LAST_NAME satisfying
       customer CUSTOMER_ID is named FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME
*/
FOREIGN KEY Order(customer_id) REFERENCES Customer(customer_id)
```

This means that those particular tables and column lists satisfy *the (one and only) relationship/association "foreign key in this database"*. (And a database will have a meta-data table for its foreign key relationship/association.)

We say that "there is a foreign key" from the first table's list of columns to the second table's list of columns. There's only one foreign key relationship/association for the database. When there is a foreign key its tables and column lists *satisfy this database's foreign key relationship*. But a foreign key isn't a relationship/association. People call foreign keys "relationships", but they are not.

But foreign keys don't matter to querying! (Ditto for any other constraint.) A query's result holds rows whose values (entity & property info) are related/associated *by that query's relationship/association*, built from conditions and *base table relationships/associations*.